# Dataproc job details not showing on the web console

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

For some reason, Google Dataproc web console is not displaying job outputs anymore. I've try using Chrome Incognito as well as Safari. The 3 blue dots keep cycling and I never see anything. Clicking "Line wrapping" didn't help. Workaround is to use the gcloud command but I kind of like to be able to see it on the console as I can check on my jobs from anywhere, not just on a machine with the gcloud tools installed.

[image]

Comment: Have you been able to reproduce that issue on different machines and/or different networks? Is it possible your network is somehow blocking requests to Google Cloud Storage, which Dataproc job output depends on? Approximately how long is the total job output when you fetch it with gcloud?

Comment: Yes I have tried at home, in the office, different computer. I think it is an issue affecting only me as another user can see the output. I have tried using incognito. At one point it was doing this (not showing output for a couple of days), then suddenly started working again and then not. And it has not worked for more than a week now.

Comment: Do you have the `storage.objectViewer` role in your project or equivalent permissions of `storage.objects.get` and `storage.objects.list`? When you run it from gcloud instead, is it maybe using a service account instead of your personal permissions? Is it possible you're signed in as two different users in your browser that have different permission levels?

Comment: Well my boss made the "owner" of the whole project and I'm still seeing the problem. He can see the job output, not me. I am launching the jobs using gcloud comment from my laptop.

Comment: It suddenly started to work again. I'm not sure why. :(